# Why does the C# Service Reference Wizard generate duplicate configuration code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap

If I look at the output of my app.config just after having made a reference to web service,  with visual 2010 service reference wizard, this is what I got in the `basicHttpBinding` node of my app.config:

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="FirmNameServiceSOAPServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="FirmNameServiceSOAPServiceSoapBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

The nodes `binding name="FirmNameServiceSOAPServiceSoapBinding"` and `binding name="FirmNameServiceSOAPServiceSoapBinding1"` are just complete dupplicate.

Do you have any idea of the reasons ? Does it helps for something ?

Comment: Is it possible you ran the wizard twice? Or for some other reason already had it set up in the config before running the wizard?

Comment: No. I have just retried again, New Project then Add Service Reference, and same result: dupplicate Bindings, just the name changes with a 1 added at the end of the second.

Comment: the security modes are different. I'm a little hazy on how webservices expose themselves.. But does it expose two securities..?

Comment: @Default as far as I can diff, no, the two security settings are the same.

Comment: @StephaneRolland does your service expose 2 basichttpbindings?

Comment: what do you mean they are the same? In the code you have posted it clearly says: `<security mode="Transport">` and `<security mode="None">`. How is that equal..?

Answer (score 0):

I have simply commented the second `<Binding>` node. Then, it still builds and executes correctly.

I do think **it's a MS Visual 2010 bug** and it is polluting the app configuration file. That doesn't help when trying to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be that your service is exposing multiple `BasicHttpBindings`. I would check your service config.

You can see what happens her with the WcfTestClient found at a similar path to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

Comment: I have checked your hypothesis. However the server-side `wsdl` expose only one `port` and only one `binding`.

Comment: @StephaneRolland the wsdl might not tell the full story.

Comment: it seems WcfTestClient.exe doesn't work with wsdl delvered through https. The app get a 401 unauthorized http error.

Comment: I entered endpoint adress set to the wsdl https url. After some seconds I got (shortened error log)`: Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://project.netweaver.ondemand.com/web/services/soap/project?wsdl If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: . `   **The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.**

Comment: I had 401 errors when I tried to access the webservice by http only. But the webservice is secured.